# Can you attack a foe outside of melee when you are in melee with someone else?

Tags: savage-worlds, melee-combat

Say that I am in melee with enemy A. Enemy B is farther away, but within my range. Can I attack B?

The only rules I see are about Ranged Weapons in

> **Ranged Weapons in Close Combat**
>
> No ranged weapon larger than a pistol may be fired at adjacent foes engaged in melee. Larger weapons may be used as clubs, however. Pistols can befired in close combat, but since the defender is actively fighting back, the TN for the Shooting roll is his Parry rather than the standard TN of 4.

However, this doesn't address being in melee and wanting to fire outside of melee. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, there are no restrictions for firing at a target outside of the melee you are in. The only penalty that might apply is a -1 cover penalty if you're firing past the person you are in melee with.

See [here](http://www.pegforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=35523&p=346327&hilit=shooting%20melee#p346327) for confirmation of this ruling by Clint Black.